# .NET Core HttpClient exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, dotnet-httpclient

I am using .NET 6 to develop the core Web API, I have a abstract class AdminApiClient inherit ApiClientBase class like below:

```
public abstract class AdminApiClient : ApiClientBase
{
    protected static HttpClient? client;

    public AdminApiClient()
    {
        client = client ?? new HttpClient
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:44355/")
        };
    }

    protected override HttpClient GetHttpClient()
    {
        return client;
    }
}
```

Below is my ApiClientBase class, When I call the Test method, declare new httpClient inside method is working fine, but when calling GetHttpClient() throw exception.

```
public abstract class ApiClientBase
{
    protected abstract HttpClient GetHttpClient();

    protected async Task<TResult> Test<TResult>()
    {
        var apiName = "api/users/GetTest";

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44355/");

        //working fine
        var response1 = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiName);

        //throw error exception
        var response2 = await GetHttpClient().GetAsync(apiName);
    }
}
```

I am not sure why using code below is fine.

```
 var response1 = await httpClient.GetAsync(apiName);
```

But throw exception when using code below:

```
var response2 = await GetHttpClient().GetAsync(apiName);
```

Exception message:

> "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
> the request.\r\n ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from
> the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed
> by the remote host..\r\n ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
> (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote
> host.\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError
> error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16
> token)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)\r\n
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   ---
> End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolea n async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken
> cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage
> request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
> Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at
> System.Net.Http.HttpClient.g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage
> request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption,
> CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts,
> CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken
> originalCancellationToken)\r\n   at
> Web.Core.ApiClientBase.Test() in
> C:\Web.Core\ApiClientBase.cs:line 76"

Comment: Log and post the full exception text. Post the *text* not images. You don't need any of the code you posted anyway, it can only *cause* problems. It doesn't abstract anything and results in socket leaks. HttpClient is meant to be reused, not disposed. Use `AddHttpClient` in your DI configuration instead and add `HttpClient` as a constructor dependency to your classes. You can use multiple [named configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#named-clients).

Comment: To properly abstract APIs use [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#typed-clients). Once you use `AddHttpClient` you can combine it with [retry policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#use-polly-based-handlers) through Polly.

Comment: As for the exception, without the actual full text one can only guess. I suspect the local web API you're calling is using a developer certificate that isn't trusted, so the HTTPS connection fails. There's probably an inner exception that says this. If that's the case, `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` will fix the problem. Working with self-signed development certificates is described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide)

Comment: Hi, I just update the question with error message, and I checked inner exception, dont have any message about developer certificate.

Comment: Instead of describing the exception text, post it. *Log* and post the output of `Exception.ToString()`. No error will say anything about developer certificates. It may say the secure channel wasn't established or that the certificate wasn't trusted, or something else. Don't force people to guess

Comment: updated again with full error message

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, I solved this issue already,, thanks for the provided link, it's useful for me to learn more about httpclient. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Using centralized configuration and AddHttpClient reduces the chance of such typos

Comment: It's a good idea, I am new to .NET Core, Is .NET Core forced to use https instead of http? my previous not .net core project was working fine buy just http, without https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behaviour is different because the addresses are different:

```
http://localhost:44355/
https://localhost:44355/
```

It looks like the API you're connecting to is http only (despite using the https-ish port 44355).

Please note that you should be able to reproduce the issue in your browser by trying to go to both addresses.

Comment: OMG, really is the "s" problem, it's working fine after change to "https". you saved my day. Thanks

Comment: Is .NET Core forced to use https instead of http?